Handle an option only if another option is used
I need to process command-line options from my Python script that correspond to the syntax
tesy.py [-h] [-a [-b]]

(This is just a simplistic example illustrating the problem; in reality my script has lots of other options.)
That is, the following synaxes are correct
test.py
test.py -h
test.py -a
test.py -a -b

but the following one is not
test.py -b

because the option -a is not specified.
Can this been done with argparse in an elegant way?
The obvious way doesn't work:
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser(description='Test script')
parser.add_argument('-a', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-b', action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()

because it would accept the invalid syntax test.py -b. Now, I could check manually if the option -a is present when the option -b is given and issue an error otherwise:
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser(description='Test script')
parser.add_argument('-a', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-b', action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.b and not args.a:
    parser.error('Option -b requires option -a.')

but that's somewhat inellegant. Is there a way for argparse to handle the syntax itself?
Or I could use some trickery (thanks, ChatGPT) like this:
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser(description='Test script')
parser.add_argument('-a', action='store_true')
args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()
if args.a:
    parser.add_argument('-b', action='store_true')
    args = parser.parse_args()
else:
    args = parser.parse_args(unknown)

and this works - but the help text (test.py -h) does not mention the option -b at all. In theory, I could override the help text by using the usage= argument of ArgumentParser but this is error-prone - my script is much more complex than this simplistic example, has lots of options, is still under development, and if I have to maintain my own usage text, I might forget to update it when I add, remove, or modify an option.
I can't use a sub-parser because those work only with positional arguments - not with options.
Maybe what I want can be done with docopt but my script's command-line processing is already built around argparse and I'd rather not have to rewrite that.
So, is there an elegant way of doing what I want with argparse? Or should I just swallow my pride and use one of the klunky ones?

Feels like you want to use subparser: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands

Why is doing your own checking after parsing 'inellegant'?  Since options can occur in any order, checks have to be done at the end of parsing.  Any ways, argparse does not have this kind of checking.  Other than the existing 'xor' check, argument interactions can get messy real quick.

@rasjani, I can't use a subparser because, as I said, those work only for positional arguments and -a is an option, not a positional argument (command).

It is possible to write custom Action subclasses that check the value of other attributes (which may be default or user set). But unless you use such an Action multiple times in a parser, it's likely to be more work.  In all the related SO that I've seen, the post parsing testing is simplest. And think about the option definitions and defaults. Ask yourself why might your user use '-b' without '-a'. Your primary goal is to understand their intentions.  Correcting them is secondary.
